# How can you make a UIView subclass which doesn't inherit from UIButton respond to the VoiceOver activation gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, voiceover

We have a custom UIView subclass that for reasons outside of the scope of this discussion cannot simply be converted to a UIButton subclass, but we still want it to respond to accessibility actions as if it were a button.

We know we can set the 'Button' trait and VoiceOver will announce it as such, but how do you actually make it respond to the user 'activating' the control by double-tapping the screen when it has the VoiceOver cursor on it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was easier than I thought.  To make any UIView respond to accessibility actions, simply implement a UITapGestureRecognizer and handle just like any other tap event.  Here's how...

```
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(labelTapped))
    testLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
    testLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Once you do that, your label will respond to accessibility actions.